# Trouble connecting to Action Cable with remote origin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I've setup a websocket on our Rails app, and have been able to connect and receive data on it from the same server.

The way I've done it now is to create a socket like this:

```
class UsersChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "users_1"
  end

  def unsubscribed

  end
end
```

and then I use javascript to open the connection with

`new WebSocket('wss://domain.com/cable/users_1');`

I then broadcast and send JSON from a page in this format:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "users_1", {
      store: {
        name: store.name,
        address: {
          full_address: location.address,
          latitude: location.latitude,
          longitude: location.longitude
        }
    }
```

When that's triggered I can see in my console that it appears. I've added this channel in JS:

```
App.cable.subscriptions.create "UsersChannel",
  received: (data) ->
    console.log data
```

Now we're working building an app with React Native and when we add this code to our app:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://domain.com/cable/users_1');

ws.onmessage = (e) => {
  console.log(e.data);
};
```

we see that it pings, but receive nothing when we trigger the broadcast. I've also added this to the config file:

```
  config.action_cable.url = 'wss://domain.com/cable'
  config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
```

Anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: I'm exactly in the same boat. Did you find anything?

Comment: Can you have a look at my answer and tell me if it worked for you please?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to solve my issue.

### Solving your issue

First thing first, in your case, you are missing the step to subscribe to a channel. You have to `send` a JSON `onopen` of your WebSocket like that :

```
JSON.stringify({
  command: 'subscribe',
  identifier: JSON.stringify({
    channel: 'MyNotificationChannel',
    user_id: userId
  })
})
```

This will trigger the `MyNotificationChannel` class `subscribed` method passing the `user_id` as a param (`params[:user_id]`).

### The Origins

Then comes the issue of Origins, which was my issue.

The WebSocket opening fails on Rails side with the message :

```
Request origin not allowed: https://loc.mydom.com:28080
```

My app is running on https://loc.mydom.com:3000/ and I have separated running server for cable which listen on port 28080.
Anyways the point here is that the message shows the origin which isn't accepted.

In the environment file (`config/environments/development.rb`) you just need to add `ActionCable.server.config.allowed_request_origins` :

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # ...
  ActionCable.server.config.allowed_request_origins = [
    'https://loc.mydom.com:3000/', # My web front app
    'https://loc.mydom.com:28080'  # The phone app
  ]
  # ...
end
```

After this, my WebSocket connects and I'm receiving the updates.